# React: Render column component as a row component in a Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, antd

I'm creating a Table component in React. I'm looking in some Table components and they create an array of columns to pass to the Table. In this columns array you can put a function to render a component inside each row in tbody.

**First Example of Ant Design (https://ant.design/components/table/):**

```
const columns = [{
  title: 'Name',
  dataIndex: 'name',
  key: 'name'
}, {
  title: 'Action',
  key: 'action',
  render: (text, record) => ( <<-- THIS FUNCTION. IT RECEIVES THE ROW RECORD AS A PARAM TOO
    <span>
      This gonna be rendered in each row of the table
    </span>
  ),
}];
```

I'm trying to figure it out a good way to create this mechanism to render a column in each row of the table body.

Is there a good example to study? I'm trying to read the source code in some components in NPM.. but it's hard to understand.

Thanks devs!

Comment: columns refers to the thead content not the tbody>tr content

Comment: @stack26 yes.. but i'm trying to figure it out how this mechanism works. How the render function in a column works as a cell row.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a basic example, Usually your Table component would receive 2 props:

- Data sorce, can be array of objects
- The column configuration, which contains the attribute name, the trick of the function is just the functional programming of javascript, you can receive render function so user can implement their own render logic.

eg.

```
const dataSource = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'aaaa',
        age: 10
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'bbbb',
        age: 11
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'ccc',
        age: 12
    },
];
```

so a column config would be like:

```
const column = [
    {
        key: 'id',
        label: 'ID'
    },
    {
        key: 'name',
        label: 'Student Name'
    },
    {
        key: 'age',
        label: 'Student Age',
        render: (text, record) => {
            return `** ${text} **`; // just for decoration
        }
    }
]
```

The table component would iterate around the datasource and with the help of column configuration to build the Table tags.

however you can always add something like this inside of your loop logic:

```
   if (typeof render === 'function') {
        cell = <td key={key}>{render(item[key], item)}</td>  // call the render function and pass the data
   } else {
        cell = <td key={key}>{item[key]}</td> // else will just render it
   }
```